# Splitting each page of a document into separate documents?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Is there a way to break an 85 page Word document into 85 separate documents?

Adobe Acrobat can do that with the "split document" feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in feature in Word to do this but you can use a macro.

```
Sub MakeSepDocs()
Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range
Dim newDoc As Word.Document, fName As String
Dim sep As String, nbr As Integer, sNbr As String
sep = Application.PathSeparator

Set doc = ActiveDocument
Selection.HomeKey Word.WdUnits.wdStory
fName = Mid(doc.FullName, InStrRev(doc.FullName, sep) + 1, _
    InStrRev(doc.FullName, ".") - InStrRev(doc.FullName, sep) - 1)
On Error Resume Next
Repeat:
Set rng = doc.Bookmarks("\page").Range
rng.Select
Set newDoc = Documents.Add
nbr = nbr + 1
sNbr = Format(nbr, "00")
newDoc.Content.FormattedText = rng.FormattedText
newDoc.SaveAs2 doc.path & sep & fName & sNbr, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
newDoc.Close
DoEvents
doc.Activate
Selection.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
If Selection.Range.Start = doc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Start Then Exit Sub
GoTo Repeat
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I create this macro? Through Visual Basic?

Comment: For procedure to follow to create a macro you can following the process described in the following article: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/CreateAMacro.htm